# Download file with curl on Mac

Tags: macos, shell, curl, wget

I want to download a file in a shell-script using curl on my Mac:

```
http://dumps.wikimedia.org/barwiki/latest/barwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2
```

However, I always get:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.11.6</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Why and what can I do?

Comment: `curl -L` the `-L` will follow redirects.

Comment: awesome, this work - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

with php i check url rediect first and then try to get

```
    <?
$url='http://xxxx/';    
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); // We'll parse redirect url from header.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE); // We want to just get redirect url but not to follow it.
$response = curl_exec($ch);
preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $response, $matches);
$data = curl_close($ch);
$turl= !empty($matches[1]) ? trim($matches[1][0]) : 'No redirect found';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $turl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$homepage=$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

i can't help you with ssh but if poosible use it with php